# Regex to identify multiple files

Tags: regex, azure, security, azure-purview

Is there a way a RegEx can identify multiple file attachments within an email?

My current RegEx only works when a single filename contains 4 or more of the file extensions.

What I need is a RegEx to trigger when 4 or more separate filenames in an email have the below file extensions.

'''(([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\.-():]){1,9}(.xls|.xlsm|.xlsx)){4,}$'''

Comment: Since you want to check several lines at once, you would need multiline regexp where you can define where to start to search and what is the last line which is part of the "list of attachments" section. Limiting your regexp to check only these lines as a whole, then you would able to check the extensions with positive lookahead assertion. Too many details would need to able to provide you further hint on this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try matching at least 4 times a pattern that start with the character class without a space followed by 0-8 times the character class with a whitespace char followed by the extension.

```
(?:[\s\S]*?[\w.():-][\w\s.():-]{0,8}\.xls[xm]?\b){4,}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uUQ5rJ/1)